# How to determine if the iPhone User is Sleeping?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion, healthkit

I want to do a sleep analysis for the user in my app.And I think the CoreMotion Framewrok should help.

```
func queryActivityStartingFromDate(start: NSDate!, toDate end: NSDate!, toQueue queue: NSOperationQueue!, withHandler handler: CMMotionActivityQueryHandler!)
```

So I use the API above to get the user motion data in the last 7 days.And Now I get a list of CMMotionActivity Object.
And My question is how to calculate the user sleep status from these thousands of CMMotionActivity Object.Is there any algorithms? Or any other way to achieve sleep analysis.
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMMotionActivity` includes a `stationary` property which might be useful in your case.

Look for contiguous periods of inactivity, paired with location, timezone & `CMDeviceMotion` data you should begin to detect patterns in the dataset you have. use statistical variation to define thresholds and fine-tune your results.

Caveat, you will make assumptions which might not be true. Some people sleep in moving vehicles for instance.

I found this pdf useful ftp://ftp.tik.ee.ethz.ch/pub/students/2010-HS/SA-2010-26.pdf

Comment: I have read the pdf for many hours,but still not got a clear algorithm to fix the problem. But It did helped me a lot. I will read it more carefully latter.

Comment: Did anyone come up with a good algorithm for taking the motion data and converting to a readable graph? I can't figure out where to begin from reading that PDF. Any example equations would greatly help me